# Need to manual update custom post after wp-all-import run

Tags: php, wordpress, wpallimport

I everyone first of all sorry for my English, not a native speaker here.

I have a problem that is probably WordPress related and not Wp-All-import fault, but this is giving me headache.

I have a custom post (Properties) which has some custom fields, one of it is a true/false checkbox to set the property as featured.

Everything is working fine, the value get updated and is actually visible in the backend, so properties that need to be set as "featured" are actually ok.

The problem is that the posts are not showing on frontend, unless I manually update them, doing so will fix the problem and show the posts correctly.

The website is kind of a mess, we took it over because the client was unhappy with his previous service, and many template files have been changed or commented not following best practice...

I had a similar problem once (well... not really) , where adding terms for a taxonomy (while creating the post or just from the classic taxonomy page) will lead to an infinite loading, that was because of too many blanks space in the functions.php, but this is not the case.

I just don't get what it could be, if manual update is working is it a wp-all-import related problem? But the import is fine, I mean the checkbox is actually set to true....but the posts are not showing unless I manually update them.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there a render cache, such as WP Rocket or similar?

Comment: +1 for cache. Check and compare the row in wp_postmeta and wp_posts before and after the manual update, maybe something else is happening. Narrow it down by deactivating all other plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that exact same problem started to happen on one of our sites recently. It all worked fine for better part of two years but since two weeks ago, I have to manually update posts after import to see the changes on frontend.

Edit: I think this might be an issue with Search & Filter Pro cache